# Modifying string on java

Tags: java, string

I must turn String type modified xpathes to real xpathes by Java;

For example;

This kind of xpathes

> _HTML_1__BODY_1__FORM_1__INPUT_3_

should turn to

> /HTML[1]/BODY[1]/FORM[1]/INPUT[3]

I have no idea, Could you please help me

Comment: What have you tried?
This http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html is a good starting point.
And, remember, String is immutable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like lateralus said, Strings are immutable, so you can't change these.

However, having said that, you can use the replaceAll to return a modified version of the String, for example in this case:

```
String input = "_HTML_1__BODY_1__FORM_1__INPUT_3_";

String output = input.replaceAll("_(\\d+)_", "[$1]").replaceAll("_", "/");
// output = /HTML[1]/BODY[1]/FORM[1]/INPUT[3]
```

**Edit**

As for an explanation of the regex used in this case:

This method uses two separate regular expressions to return a modified String. Firstly, "`_(\\d+)_`", looks for numbers surrounded by two underscore characters `_`, `\\d` is a regex short hand for any digit.  The surrounding brackets `(...)` capture the number, so that we can reference it in the replacement string.

When we make the first replacement, we replace with `[$1]`, in here `$1` refers back to the first captured group, i.e. the digit captured, and surrounds it in square brackets `[...]`. The underscores are also removed, as these were captured in the expression, if not in the group.

The second `replaceAll` call simply replaces all remaining underscore characters with a `/`.

Comment: Please, add more explanations on regular expressions for OP.

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg I don't see why he should. The OP can research that topic if he chooses to.

Comment: @Duncan he may just add something like "for more information, google for regular expression replace" or smth like this.

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg explanation added as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use a state machine:

```
 public static void main(String []args){
    String inp = "_HTML_1__BODY_1__FORM_1__INPUT_3_";

    String out = "";
    int state = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<inp.length(); i++) {
        if (inp.charAt(i) == '_') {
            switch (state) {
                case 0:
                    out += "/";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    out += "[";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    out += "]";
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new RuntimeException();
            }
            // Next state
            state = (state + 1) % 3;
        } else {
            out += inp.charAt(i);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(out);
    // Returns "/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/FORM[1]/INPUT[3]"
 }
```

Comment: It's better not to use `+=`, when you're constructing `String` in many steps, here you should use `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder`, or, easily regular expression replace, as @PeterK suggested.

Comment: Of course, I thought OP was mainly interested in an idea how to start with this, not in a millisecond optimized helper function. That said, I would also prefer a regex solution..

Comment: Okay, you're using DFA instead of using regular expression? Why should this make sense, if you don't want to make performance the best?

Comment: There is no deep reason behind this - it was just the first idea that popped up and before the smarter regexp answer was posted.