# extracting numbers from string and modifying them in java

Tags: java, string

I want increase the numbers in a string.

For example; I want to modify

> "HTML[0].BODY[0]/UL[1]/LI[10]/A[1]"

to

> "HTML[1].BODY[1]/UL[2]/LI[11]/A[2]"

Note: I accept the answer, but I want to add my tryings;
`replace("8", "9").replace("7", "8").replace("6", "7").replace("5", "6").replace("4", "5").replace("3", "4").replace("2", "3").replace("1", "2").replace("0", "1")`
and I realize that 9 could not change so I tried

```
for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i)))
        {
            int a=Integer.parseInt(s, s.charAt(i))+1;
            s.charAt(i)=(char)a;
            System.out.println(s.charAt(i));

        }
        }
```

This did not work also..
second note: Generally, I tried to write all codes, and due to points I get an warning. And I did not want to write part of codes

Comment: you are wrong. and biased. I tried everything, but I could not post  codes due to my points

Comment: There's no restriction on posting your code, no matter your points. So you didn't even try to post your code...

Comment: there is a restriction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this. I'll share one:

```java
String input = "HTML[0].BODY[0]/UL[1]/LI[10]/A[1]";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(m.group()) + 1));
}
m.appendTail(sb);

String output = sb.toString();

System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: I don't know if doing other people's work is a good answer...

Comment: it is a good answer. and among all answers to same type of questions, it is the only one that answers detect and modify the digit in a string

Comment: Hey @ydmpcn I saw your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26297243/modifying-string-on-java). Already have long since that question. So I believe you when you say you tried many things. By the way, you can also upvote in the answer. ;)

Comment: Yes I tried this also:) But it requires 15 points